# Making libcurl CodeLite Project

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, libcurl, codelite

I have downloaded Curl and would like to add libcurl only (no other stuffs) to my CodeLite Workspace. I have seen VC Project files but I do not use VC (and I use Primarily Ubuntu).
So I need help to know which files to Include and any pre-processor that I need to include for the library to compile.

I have tried adding all `*.c/*.h` files but I keep getting errors (if those errors can be of help I will post them). Add the include folder in curl root directory does not help either.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information before anyone can tell you what you are doing wrong?  Do you get a compile error?  A linker error?  What is the error?  Your question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with compiling library with terminal and just tell CL to find it there!